# java.lang.IllegalStateException: can not found call #0 on stack. Invalid call of record method?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, spock

I am writing spock tests for web application and just recently began getting this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: can not found call #0 on stack. Invalid 
call of record method? at Test.Simple Test(Test.groovy:8)
```

Even when I do a simple sanity check (shown below) I still get this error. It tells me the error comes from whatever comes after the "then" clause.

```
import spock.lang.Specification

class Test extends Specification {
    def "Simple Test"() {
        when:
        def x = 1
        then:
        x
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please copy/paste the COMPLETE exception message and stack trace into your post (format as code).

Comment: @JimGarrison - Added the full exception message and formatted as code.

Comment: did you try using a truthy value instead, e.g. `then: x == 1`?

Comment: @laenger Yeah, same exception

Comment: Does this happen in an IDE or in maven/gradle, or everywhere?

Comment: @LeonardBrünings Updated the tags. Eclipse is the IDE and I am using gradle

Comment: Could you clone and run the official https://github.com/spockframework/spock-example project and see if you have the same issues there?

Comment: Are you perhaps using Nebula and running into [this issue](https://github.com/spockframework/spock/issues/714)? I found the reference on Google, I was just curious.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution after a lot of looking around. This project was a multi-project gradle build and I found that the parent project had a conflicting testCompile spock dependency with the sub-project that the test was in.

Thank you to all who looked into this issue!